# "Upper-case" is to "capital" as "lowercase" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, capitalization, analogy

Is there a corresponding word to go with capital to mean lower-case?

Comment: Computer geeks informally say "no caps"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are capital letters and **small** letters.

In a formal or technical context I would use "lower-case" to avoid seeming like a young child talking about big letters and small letters.

Comment: There are also small capital letters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps.

Comment: Argh.  Blast you, Small Caps.  It was all becoming so clear.

Comment: [" Our chief weapon is surprise...surprise and fear...fear and surprise.... Our two weapons are fear and surprise...and ruthless efficiency.... Our *three* weapons ...](http://people.csail.mit.edu/paulfitz/spanish/script.html)

Answer (score 24):

In typography and calligraphy the corresponding terms are *majuscule* and *minuscule*:

See the Wikipedia entry on [Capital letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_letter). *Minuscule* also serves as the counterpart of *capital*.

Answer (score 7):

For this analogy question, *small* is the word you are looking for:

*uppercase : capital :: lowercase : small*

> **small**  *(adj)*:
>   lowercase
>
> ---
>
> <sup>[Definition 1b of *small* in Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/small)</sup>

Comment: Wow.  I had no idea.

Answer (score 6):

*Minuscule* is also the word for them, although I doubt most people would know what you were talking about.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no equivalent (Like Pedi-Letter or something "Foot" related instead of "Head" related.)

You have the following options

1. lowercase
2. lowercase letter
3. minuscule
4. small letter

Although I do not recommend 3 unless you are amongst typographers, nor 4 (you will sound childish).

Comment: I think you will sound just as childish in North America if you use 4

Comment: @Kevin - Fixed :D

Comment: shoeital?
sockital?

Answer (score 0):

The word is actually "**uncapitalized**".  It is "Upper case" to "capital letter" as "lower-case" is to "uncapitalized letter".

(Uncapitalized is an adjective, so "uncapitalized word".  There is no noun form, "Uncapital" or anything like, as far as I know, though "non-capital" might be intuitive in context)

Granted, it's a bit clunky - one reason uncapitalized letters are usually referred to as "letters" with no modification.  But when it is necessary to specify, one might end up saying something like "those words are actually  uncapitalized", or else "when you type in that password, make sure to leave the h uncaptitalized", or "captial D, the rest is uncapitalized".

> **Uncapitalized**:  not capitalized, such as, not written in capitals or with an initial capital.  "An uncapitalized word".  - From [Mirriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncapitalized)

or

> Capitalize: to write or print in capital letters letters or with an initial capital letter.  Related forms: capitalizable, adjective; capitalizer, noun; **noncapitalized**, adjective; **uncapitalized**, adjective
>   - from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/uncapitalized)